# bandwidth difference beetween apache qpid and rabbitmq when reconnect

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, qpid

I developed program to publish messages and then consume it at `10 ms` interval for `30 s` duration. When it runs for `5 s`, it will disconnect and reconnect after `5 s` but still produce messages. `Apache Qpid` need at least `4 s` to consume all the messages but `RabbitMQ` only need `2 s`. I guessed there is maximum bandwidth to publish messages. What caused this? Is `amqp 0.9.1` lighter then `amqp 1.0`? Or there are any reasons?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific and add how you've measured those times?

Comment: I have 2 virtual os, 1 as a client (to publish and subscribe) and another one as server (broker for amqp). client will generate message with interval 10 ms then, after around 5 seconds client will connect to server. There are around 250 - 300 messages (1024 byte each). Qpid need almost 4 seconds to consume and Rabbitmq only around 2 seconds. What caused this difference? Is there any bandwidth limitation between amqp 0.9.1 and amqp 1.0? or it just config problem in Qpid or Rabbitmq? thanks

Comment: The messaging delivery guarantee offered by the messaging provider to your application has a huge bearing on overall performance of the system.  It influences the messaging packets that need to flow to and fro over the network and how the messaging provider uses storage.   If you have not done so already,  you need to first decide what delivery guarantee your application requires,  then make sure you configure Rabbit or Qpid to provide the guarantee you require.   This usually mean configuration on both the client and server sides.   This will allow you to conduct a fair test.